# Can I use two different antenna on a WRT54GL?

Tags: linksys

I have my WRT54GL set up as a bridge.

I currently have 15db high gain omni-directional antennaand wanted to add a second directional antenna to boost my gain.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. The device only has one wLAN card in it, so it uses [diversity antennas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antenna_diversity). Basically when it's listening for a signal, it uses the antenna where the signal is coming in the strongest.

It may improve the signal strength to add a second directional antenna. Note you'll lose much of the local service area if you're using it as a repeater as well. Additionally the best signal would probably be obtained from a single higher gain antenna than two lower gain antennas (but this would depend on your [environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-line-of-sight_propagation) and what's in the [Fresnel zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_zone)).

Many of the newer devices have just one antenna as it's cheaper, and the drop in range in a simple environment (little or no steel and concrete near the LOS) is minimal.